# Passing array as argument to a module in SystemVerilog Xilinx

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I have declared the following systemverilog module:

```
module module_top
    (
        input  logic                              clk,
        input  logic                              rst,
        input  logic signed [7  : 0 ] x_in,
        input  logic signed [5  : 0 ] y_in [24:0]
    );
    module_1 module_1_inst_1( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[4 : 0 ]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_2( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[9 : 5 ]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_3( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[14: 10]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_4( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[19: 15]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_5( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[24: 20]));
endmodule

module module_1
    (
        input  logic                              clk,
        input  logic                              rst,
        input  logic signed [7 : 0 ] x_in,
        input  logic signed [5 : 0 ] y_in [4:0]
    );
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    $display("INFO: ", $sformatf("y_in=%p", y_in));
end

endmodule
```

I am using Vivado 2018.2 to run a functional test on this module. I pass the following array in my testbench to module_top:

```
    y_in =  {
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b000000,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111
            };
```

When I look in wavforms, all the instantiation of module_1 are getting the correct y_in slice excpet module_1_inst_2. Supersingly to me, I am getting Z for y_in in module_1_inst_2. For instance if I run simulation, since I am printing y_in values every pos edge of clock, I am getting the following:

```
INFO: y_in='{15,15,15,15,15}
INFO: y_in='{6'bzzzzzz,6'bzzzzzz,6'bzzzzzz,6'bzzzzzz,0}
INFO: y_in='{15,15,15,15,15}
INFO: y_in='{15,15,15,15,15}
INFO: y_in='{15,15,15,15,15}
```

However, if I move this print one level up the hierarchy (module_top), y_in has all the values correctly. I got the same observation when I checked the waveform.

On the otherhand, if I change the y_in width from 6 to 7 bits it works! So I am guessing Xilinx does not properly support passign arrays to modules? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you using `y_in = {...}`? if so, you are assigning a concatenated bit stream to an unpacked array. It does not work this way. Try add apostrophe in front of `{`,: `y_in = '{...}`

Comment: I added apostrophe and still got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to give a complete example like below, that works fine with other simulators. Either array concatenation `{,,,}` or assignment pattern `'{,,,}` should work.
So I suspect you either have a tool issue, or something wrong with what you have not shown.

```
module module_top
    (
        input  logic                              clk,
        input  logic                              rst,
        input  logic signed [7  : 0 ] x_in,
        input  logic signed [5  : 0 ] y_in [24:0]
    );
    module_1 module_1_inst_1( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[4 : 0 ]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_2( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[9 : 5 ]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_3( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[14: 10]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_4( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[19: 15]));
    module_1 module_1_inst_5( .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .x_in(x_in), .y_in(y_in[24: 20]));
endmodule

module module_1
    (
        input  logic                              clk,
        input  logic                              rst,
        input  logic signed [7 : 0 ] x_in,
        input  logic signed [5 : 0 ] y_in [4:0]
    );
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  $display("%m INFO: ", $sformatf("y_in=%p", y_in));
end

endmodule
module top;
  logic signed [5  : 0 ] y_in [24:0];
  bit clk,rst;
  logic signed [7  : 0 ] x_in;
  module_top dut (.*);
  always #2 clk++;
  initial begin
     y_in =  {
                1,2,3,4,5,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b000000,
                6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111, 6'b001111
            };
    #10 $finish;
  end
endmodule
```